# Weird behaviour variadic argument template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I tasked myself in writing a function that would accept generic STL containers, and came up with this design:

```
template<template<class, class...> class C,
         class... A,
         class T = typename C<A...>::value_type>
void wrong( std::vector<C<T, A...>>& indexes, std::vector<T>& resultSet ) {
    resultSet.push_back(indexes[0][0]);
}
```

That was my first attempt which was blatantly wrong but that worked so I skipped on that then I spotted the mistake during code review and wrote the following which is more correct

```
template<template<class...> class C,
         class... A,
         class T = typename C<A...>::value_type>
void correct( std::vector<C<A...>>& indexes, std::vector<T>& resultSet ) {
    resultSet.push_back(indexes[0][0]);
}
```

Let's say that the above code is used in the following:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 {1,2}, v2{3,4};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> sets {v1, v2};
    std::vector<int> r;

    wrong(sets, r);
    std::cout << r.back() << std::endl;
    r.clear();

    correct(sets, r);
    std::cout << r.back() << std::endl;

}
```

Compiling I get the same (and intended) behaviour but I feel that the first wrong function should have failed since the "C" type takes three types as argument being ***int, int, Allocator***.
The behavior of the second one matches my understanding of templates.

The question is: what is going on in template deduction of the above?

Comment: Exactly but then it should fail at this stage std::vector<C<T, A...>> since it takes std::vector<int, int, Allocator>

Comment: If you use GCC or similar you can `std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;` to see what the template parameters are deduced to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can deduce that `C = std::vector`, as it can take 1 or more template arguments (in this case `int` and `Allocator`). We then deduce that `A` must be the allocator used with the vector. Finally `T` is deduced to be `int` (we do not use the default argument in this case). If we write this out, we get

```
void wrong(std::vector<std::vector<int, Allocator>>& indexes, std::vector<int>& resultSet);
```

which we can see is well formed and can be called with our arguments.

The parameter pack `A` is deduced to the single value of `Allocator` because if we remove the first template parameter of `std::vector` we are simply left with one other parameter, which `A` deduces to.

Comment: class T = typename C<A...>::value_type

Then T would be of type Allocator in my sample.

And it should fail, at least I think this what would happen with your reasoning above but am not sure.

Comment: But `T` is deduced, so the default argument is thrown out.